# COBOL display all duplicates from a file

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I have a file which includes a list of different names. Some of some show up twice or more.

I want to display all artists which show up in this list twice or more.

How do I proceed?

Thanks in advance,

Sloan

Comment: Are the records in "Artist" sequence? If they are then just save the artist before reading the next record. Compare the artist on the new record against the saved artist. The same? Display. If not in sequence then do it manually writing down the steps. Then code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The question misses the code that describes the data and the things you have tried. If you want to do this in a COBOL program I suggest to read the documentation of the SORT statement, it might be usable for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to do this in a JCL SORT:

```
//SORT30 EXEC PGM=SYNCSORT,COND=(8,LT),            
//             PARM=('INCORE=OFF,DYNALLOC=SYSDA',EQ
//*                                                
//STEPLIB INCLUDE MEMBER=SYSTEP00                  
//        INCLUDE MEMBER=SYSORT00                  
//*                                                
//SORTIN   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=AA.YOUR.INPUT.FILE  
//SORTOUT  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=AA.YOUR.OUTPUT.FILE   
//SORTXSUM DD  SYSOUT=*  
//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*                            
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*                            
//SORTMSG  DD  SYSOUT=*  
//SYSIN   DD   *          
  SORT  FIELDS=(1,26,CH,A)
  SUM FIELDS=NONE,XSUM    
/*                        
//*
```

the SORTXSUM SYSOUT will have the duplicates in there. Just modify the `FIELD=` to the position of the artist data

Comment: While I personally would prefer SORT over COBOL any time: I think since the question is tagged "opencobol" the OP might not be on z/OS so SORT might not be available.

Comment: @piet.t true, i'll leave it here just incase this does help OP of someone in the future. The only other way (that makes sense) I can think of is to make the file a VSAM file with an alternate index on artist then search the file.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the file is small you can store the data in WS and write a simple sort, such as buble sort on the field that has duplicate data. If the file is large (which is probably not your case), you should either use External Sort or Internal Sort, then pick duplicates. If you don't care about resources, create A KSDS and load it from file.